# Windows 7 Symantec Endpoint Protection Problem

Tags: windows-7, symantec, anti-virus, blocking

In my company, we use symantec endpoint prodection. But i have an update problem like this.

[image]

How can i solve it? Can Windows 7 block symantec update?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ensure your Endpoint definitions are being updated. Put in a firewall exception for Symantec updates

Answer (score 3):

Another issue (that my company sometimes experiences with this) is that Symantec doesn't start up as fast as Windows 7 would like after you first turn on and log in to the computer, so it will think that Symantec is turned off and warn you about it. After a few minutes Symantec will start up and the action center messages will clear themselves.

Comment: +1 Have seen this very often with SEP and Win 7 and XP clients